# How to apply this code to get mysql to php output?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a database with a html output to show the data from my 4 tables.
The 4 tables have been made through normalization from 1 big table.

I have done this with just 1 table after getting the mysql_query(select bla bla)

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo $row["Kod_Barang"].'  nex row '.$row["Nama_Barang"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
```

The coding i currently have

```
<?php

    $resultstok   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Kod_Rak, Harga, Tarikh_Jual from stok");
    $resultbarang = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Nama_Barang, Bil_Barang from barang");
    $resultlokasi = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Jenis_Barang from lokasi");
    $resulttarikh = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Tarikh_Beli from tarikh");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultstok) > 0) {
    $rowstok = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultstok);
    $rowbarang = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reseltbarang);
    $rowlokasi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultlokasi);
    $rowtarikh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttarikh);

    while

}
?>
```

I expect to get each of the data out but i dont know how to apply the first code into the 2nd

Comment: Are the tables in relation between each others?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code. You're using the wrong `fetch_assoc` here.

Comment: @tadman so i have seen my careless mistake in there but after i change it what can i do to get my desired output?

Comment: @Cid i did have the tables connected but then i changed it to only primary keys and nothing else done to the table as my teacher said to not do too much

Comment: That's why I'm saying to use the object-oriented style. It's impossible to mess up like that. As for your question, we have no idea what that data is or how it's supposed to be displayed. You're selecting a bunch of columns from some tables with names that mean nothing to us, and there's no indication as to what's in there, or what you want to see.

Comment: @tadman well in my school the teachers dont teach and dont know how to do mysql and php but we are expected to produce this thing so im not so sure what and how to use here. If you could give me some tips or where can i look up to know what i need for this it would be much welcomed................. just ignore the column names as its in my local language .    edit : i also have no clue what is object oriented style

Comment: The [official documentation has examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php) where you do `$connection->query(...)` instead.

Comment: @MichaelSWS since your tables are connected, you want to "link" them using Foreign Keys. Then, you should take a look at `JOIN` keyword